# NOT NULL constraint on a column when another column has a particular value

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

```
create table test (
    col1 varchar(20),
    col2 varchar(20)
)
```

1. When col1 has value '1', col2 cannot be null.
2. When col1 has any other value, col2 can be null.

Is there a way to write a check constraints based on values of particular columns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write a table-level constraint, sure.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    col1 VARCHAR(20),
    col2 VARCHAR(20),
    CHECK (col1 != '1' OR col2 IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Either `col1` isn't `'1'` (and col2 can be anything), or `col1` is `'1'` (and `col2` can't be null).

See the [third example in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html).